# How to use deno in production

Tags: javascript, deno

I tried **Deno** (https://deno.land/) in local pc and some of its examples and we have to run the server before executing the APIs in the local environment.

I need to host it in the server so that I can call that API when we request, but i don't know how to do it.

I have the experience in hosting **PHP,.NET** in production mode i haven't used **Nodejs** yet so i don't know that process.

Comment: I might be wrong but arent Deno and NodeJS two different systems? They are not the same right (even though both allow you to run Javascript outside your browser)?

Comment: @Mathyn, Yes both are entirely different but they are javascript I don't know how to use them in production mode.

Comment: @Mathyn NodeJS and deno, both use V8 engine by chrome as a runtime to run Javascript.

Comment: Compared to other server setups Node and Deno actually are similar...if you want to spin up a server you need to install the Deno runtime on your server machine, then add your project code and run it...

Comment: @AshwynHorton Deno was created by NodeJS creator himself. He wanted to create a secure runtime as well as a better package manager solution (npm is a big ball of mud)

Comment: Here is how you can install https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/installation, and here is a base tutorial to get started on an API, https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-deno-handbook#your-first-deno-app-for-real-

Answer (score 18):

You can use the cloud provider of your preference, AWS, DigitalOcean, Azure... and [install](https://deno.land/x/install/) `deno` and then you can use `pm2` using [`interpreter`](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#start-any-process-type) flag to automatically restart if the server crashes and/or start the server on boot.

The easiest way is to create an `ecosystem.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "app",
      script: "./deno.js",
      interpreter: "deno",
      interpreterArgs: "run --allow-net --allow-read",
    },
  ],
};
```

And use `interpreterArgs` to pass arguments that you need to pass to `deno`.

Now all you need to do is:

```
pm2 start
```

Now your server will be available on whatever port you setup your server. You can use Nginx as a reverse proxy if you want too.

*You can also use any process manager of your preference*

Comment: where to put the DENO_DIR that is set before the deno run command?

Answer (score 11):

You can just use:

```
pm2 start index.ts --interpreter="deno" --interpreter-args="run --allow-net"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider containerising your application with the official [`denoland/deno` Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/denoland/deno), which you can deploy to the likes of AWS Fargate, Kubernetes or even just Docker running on a static Linux machine if a container orchestration platform is excessive for your particular needs. Here's a Dockerfile I wrote based upon said image for a [Deno microservice](https://github.com/reno-router/blog-microservice):

```
# Production Dockerfile that caches
# project dependencies at build time

FROM denoland/deno:1.15.3

ARG postgres_host
ARG postgres_user
ARG postgres_password
ARG postgres_db
ARG postgres_pool_connections

COPY . /microservice
WORKDIR /microservice
USER deno

ENV POSTGRES_HOST=$postgres_host
ENV POSTGRES_USER=$postgres_user
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$postgres_password
ENV POSTGRES_DB=$postgres_db
ENV POSTGRES_POOL_CONNECTIONS=$postgres_pool_connections

RUN ["deno", "cache", "deps.ts"]
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["run", "--allow-env", "--allow-net", "service/server.ts"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share the command I use

```
pm2 start main.ts --interpreter="deno" --interpreter-args="run --allow-env --allow-net --allow-read --unstable --no-prompt" --name "my-cool-app" -- start --production
```

You already know the Deno flags: `--allow-env`, `--allow-net`, `--allow-read`, `--unstable`.

`--no-prompt` disables Deno from asking if you want to enable flags that something in your app requires and you forgot to allow.

`--name` is for pm2. When you run `pm2 list` or `pm2 status`, you see the name of your app, instead of some generic name.

`--production` is just an extra flag I gave my application.

---

Thanks to [Aral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4467741/aral-roca)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62447952) for putting me on the right track.